# node.js / jade not able to pass values with form calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to get an "out-of-the-box" app to work with node.js 0.8.0 (it was designed in 0.6.x but I couldn't get the dependencies to work with that).

I have updated most of the errors with the views that I have found, but am having troubles passing variables through form fields.

Login Page:

```
extends ../layout

block scripts
  include ../includes/js/jquery
  include ../includes/js/center
  include ../includes/js/focus
  include ../includes/js_form

block content

  include ../includes/logo

  .main

    h1 Welcome to <br> #{company_name} #{company_location}!
    br
    h2 Please sign in / sign out.
    br

    form(action='check_signout', method='post', id='name_form', autocomplete='off')
      p What is your first name?
      input(type='text', id='first_name', name='first_name', size='40', class='required', minlength='1')
      br
      br
      p And your last name?
      input(type='text', id='last_name', name='last_name', size='40', class='required', minlength='2')
      br

      include ../includes/next

  include ../includes/page_number
```

check_signout (form submission page):

```
extends ../layout

block scripts
  include ../includes/js/jquery
  include ../includes/js/center
  include ../includes/timeout

block content

  include ../includes/logo

  .main

    h2 &nbsp;

    p Hi, #{first_name} #{last_name}!
    p You signed in at #{signin_time}.
    p Would you like to sign out?

    br
    br
    br

    p
      input.button#signout(type="button", value="Yes, I would like to sign out.", onclick="parent.location='confirm_signout'", readonly)

    br
    br

    p
      input.button(type="button", value="No, I would like to sign in.", onclick="parent.location='reason'", readonly)
```

Error:

```
Express
500 TypeError: Cannot set property 'first_name' of undefined
at exports.check_signout (/home/ubuntu/lobby/routes/index.js:24:31)
at callbacks (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:165:11)
at param (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139:11)
at pass (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:146:5)
at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
at Object.router (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:37:5)
at next (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at store.get.next (/home/ubuntu/lobby/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:302:9)
```

Comment: You are posting to another HTML page directly from your login page? You have to pass first_name to check_signout from the server.

Comment: copy the express code... search for  app.engine('jade'...

Comment: I know nothing of nodejs (making this much more difficult than it needs to be for me), let me find that in the app.js code and update the original question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AtXQn/ there's the app.js, it's just posting the view to the html page.

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/Lobby-App that's also the git for it, if it helps describe my issue.

Answer (score 0):

your html code looks fine, but the error is on node.js code.

Post the node.js code first.

Error 500 is displayed, so it's a "code error", check the parameters in node.js are coded correctly, also check the post request handling code is proper.